# Accessing data files in Objective-C or cocoa

Tags: objective-c

I am fairly new to a objective-c or in whole mac/iphone development. My question is how can I acces a data files(text files or flat files) in objective-c? For example I have a sample.txt file, how can I open this files and access its data? Do I need to use a class? And I heard about dictionary, is this term related to my problems?

Please kindly redirect me to a good site.

Thanks alot.

sasayins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular `fopen` and `fread` to access the contents of a file. Alternatively, you can use `NSString` if your file contains only text or `NSData` for non-text data.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file"];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file"];
```

#### Edit

`@"/path/to/file"` a constant “Objective-C” style string. It is different to a regular C string (i.e. without the `@` prepended) because it behaves like an object; you can send it messages, and it is able to be stored in `NSArray`s etc. From a Mac Programmer's point of view, these Objective-C strings can be treated just like `NSString` objects.

The Mac OS X filesystem layout typically looks like this:

```
    /System          contains system files similar to C:\windows\
    /Library         contains libraries, similar to C:\windows\system32\
    /Users           similar to Windows' C:\Documents and Settings\
    /Applications    Mac's version of C:\Program Files\
    /Developer       Where Xcode, SDKs, and other developer tools live.
```

If your username on your Mac is "smith", then your Home directory is `/Users/smith`. If you have a file in your `Documents` folder of your Home directory called `data.txt`, then you can use the following code to access it (but I wouldn't recommend hard-coding paths like this)

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/smith/Documents/data.txt"];
```

There are various functions available for reliably obtaining your home directory and other directories of particular interest. The [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation explains the various methods available for manipulating strings containing paths.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the quick answer. I have a question, what do you mean about the non-text data?

Comment: non-text data is binary data that is not (initially) meant to be printed to the screen in a human-readable way. E.g., an image file.

Comment: oh I see. thanks. What about the string path? Can you clarify about the string path? thanks.